# How to bind a column header in listview control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, eval

I want to bind a listview control with a datatable , whose column names are not fixed. And i want to display these column names in the page ?
How to achieve this ?

Comment: Could you tell us what you've tried so far? And maybe give us some related questions that you've looked at. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what exactly you want to do but this is the example of listview that you can set header name whatever you want.

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" GroupPlaceholderID="group" GroupItemCount="1" ItemPlaceholderID="item" runat="server">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="group"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <GroupTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="item"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </tr>
            </GroupTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <td>
                    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0"  border="1" style="width: 200px; height: 100px">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <span>
                                    <%# Eval("Id") %>
                                </span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                Name: <span><%# Eval("Field_name_of_your_DB") %></span><br />
                                Number: <span><%# Eval("Field_name_of_your_DB") %></span><br />
                                Date: <span><%# Eval("Field_name_of_your_DB", "{0:MM dd, yyyy}") %></span><br />
                                Comment: <span><%# Eval("Field_name_of_your_DB") %></span><br />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

And, be sure that autogeneratecolumn = false to avoid displaying data twice.